# How to check security level of a secure service?

Tags: security, https, client-server

My client-secure algorithm need a [Random oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle)... And I am using a HTTPS webservice for it, 
  https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=0&max=255&col=1&base=16&format=plain&rnd=new

... But many people notice that

> random numbers transferred over the public internet are not cryptographically secure for most purposes

... So, the question is:

- the described architecture **is secure?**  Need to use HTTPS POST instead GET? Need to add some cryptographic layer in the response?
- there are a way to check/quantify "how much secure" is it, to compare with another solutions?

### Context

It is not "so simple" and I really need a webservice, that is like a *random oracle*, must be an exteral device input (the [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine))...  I can't use a local client algorithm (ex. local [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)).  The focus in the question is the secure communication protocol, for a very simple webservice (simple and fast RPC).

---

PS: here a javascript fragment example of client-side service request: 
`xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true)` where `url` is the *random.org* link above.

Comment: Thanks @zaph, I edited providing "context" ... The language can be  Javascript as the fragment.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most systems provide a [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) (CPRNG), use that.

Per the *context* update use HTTPS and pin the certificate so you know there is no MITM and you are contacting the correct site. Note that you still have to trust the site.